# setIcon do not change on googlemap api v3 jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have an application with google maps for a mobile device. I use jquery mobile scripts.
When an user click on a marker then the icon has to change. Whoever no changes are visible. To control the script, temporary i had built in two alerts to check if the icon is changed. The alerts shows the right change but not the map. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
var mobileDemo = { 'center': '52.3702157,4.8951679', 'zoom': 10 };
var marker;

$('#gps_map').live('pageinit', function() {
    demo.add('gps_map', function() {
        $('#map_canvas_2').gmap({center: mobileDemo.center, zoom: mobileDemo.zoom, zoomControl: true, disableDefaultUI:true, callback: function(map) {
            var self = this;
            var markers = new Array();
            downloadUrl("map_genxml.php?projectid=1&campid=23", function(data) {            

              var xml = data.responseXML;
              var tekst=[];
              var meetid=[];
              var icoon=[];
              markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
              for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                tekst[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("tekst");
                meetid[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("meetid");
                icoon[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("icoon");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                if (icoon[i]=="groen") {
                  var icon = 'http://www.mijnmonitoring.nl/icons/green-dot.png';
                } else {
                  var icon = 'http://www.mijnmonitoring.nl/icons/grijs-dot.png';
                }
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: point,
                  icon: icon,
                  bounds: true
                });
                bindInfoWindow(marker, tekst[i], meetid[i], i);
                $('#map_canvas_2').gmap('addMarker',marker).click(function() {
                });
              }
            });
        }});
    }).load('gps_map');
});

function bindInfoWindow(marker, info, meetid, i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
 alert(marker.getIcon());
                  marker.setIcon('http://www.mijnmonitoring.nl/icons/red-dot.png');
 alert(marker.getIcon());
                  document.getElementById('meetpunt').innerHTML=info;
                  document.getElementById('formulier').style.display='block';

    });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

$('#gps_map').live('pageshow', function() {
    demo.add('gps_map', function() { $('#map_canvas_2').gmap('refresh'); }).load('gps_map');
});
```

Comment: maybe explain a bit more of your alrge code, or try to reduce it to a snippet thats describing the problem more specific ;)

Comment: Dear @Zaibis, i have made testsite for it: http://www.mijnmonitoring.nl/mobile/test.php#gps_map so you can see how its work. When you click on a marker you see the alerts but not the changing on the map. Is this clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to debug your code without being able to run the page locally and it would help a lot if you could create a jsfiddle.

However, I believe that the below solution will work in your case. Replace the contents of the *bindInfoWindow* method with the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
    return function() {
            marker.setIcon("http://www.mijnmonitoring.nl/icons/red-dot.png");
            document.getElementById('meetpunt').innerHTML=info;
            document.getElementById('formulier').style.display='block';
    }
})(marker));
```

I have created a working example which shows how to change the map's markers icons (grijs-dot.png, red-dot.png):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var cityList = [
                ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
                ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
            ],
            demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87),
            map;

            function initialize()
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 7,
                   center: demoCenter,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                var marker, 
                i,
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        icon: 'http://www.mijnmonitoring.nl/icons/grijs-dot.png',
                        title: cityList[i][0]
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            marker.setIcon("http://www.mijnmonitoring.nl/icons/red-dot.png");
                            infowindow.setContent(cityList[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            }
            $(document).on("pageinit", "#basic-map", function() {
                initialize();
                addMarkers();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @JeanBoumans: Also, remove `.click(function() {});` from `$('#map_canvas_2').gmap('addMarker',marker).click(function() {});` because this way you override the click event handler..

Comment: Dear Tolis, thank you for seeking a solution. But is still not functioning well. You can try it on the same hyperlink as above. I have made also a jsfiddle. I am new at this forum is a link to it enough or have i to edit in this? [http://jsfiddle.net/dru9N/]

Comment: @JeanBoumans Did you remove the `.click(function() {});` from `$('#map_canvas_2').gmap('addMarker',marker).click(function() {});` as well? Please remove it and retry :)

Comment: @TolisEmmannouilidis I haven't seen that message but now i have removed it, but (i'am sorry) still not function well.

Comment: I have also rewrite rest of the script as you suggested and now is function well. Thanks a lot. (But I still don't understand why my own script went wrong).